# why outside the funtion the pointer data is not getting updated

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt

I am new to c++ I am trying to update the similar variable using one function

I have a variable

```
IComponent* m_component1;
IComponent* m_component2;
IComponent* m_component3;
```

then I have set function  IComponent is and interface

```
void SetComponent1(IComponent* comp) { SetComponent(comp, m_component1); }
void SetComponent2(IComponent* comp) { SetComponent(comp, m_component2); }
void SetComponent3(IComponent* comp) { SetComponent(comp, m_component3); }

void SetComponent(IComponent* newComp , IComponent* oldComp)
{
    if (oldComp)
    {
        oldComp->Clean();
    }
    newComp->Load();
    oldComp = newComp;
}
```

but my m_component1/2/3 is still Saying its null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're passing in `oldComp` as pointer by value. So setting this pointer to anything will only change the pointer locally in the function.

Pass the pointer by reference if you want to affect the original pointer passed in.